# Syslog-ng cannot parse messages correctly from orbi router

Tags: syslog-ng

I configured my Orbi Pro 6 router to send logs to syslog-ng.
Syslog-ng receives all logs. It's cool.
But some messages are not processed correctly and I don't know what to do I'm a newbie.

Here is a correctly processed message:

```
[2024-02-16T22:14:11.765300] Incoming log entry; input='<13>Feb 16 21:14:11 root: [WLAN access rejected: incorrect security] from MAC address XX,\x0a', msg='0x7feb13e22000', rcptid='0'
[2024-02-16T22:14:11.765300] json-parser(): no marker at the beginning of the message, skipping JSON parsing ; input='[WLAN access rejected: incorrect security] from MAC address XX,', marker='@cee:'
[2024-02-16T22:14:11.765300] json-parser(): no marker at the beginning of the message, skipping JSON parsing ; input='[WLAN access rejected: incorrect security] from MAC address XX,', marker='@cim:'
[2024-02-16T22:14:11.765436] Outgoing message; message='<13>1 2024-02-16T21:14:11+01:00 YY root - - - [WLAN access rejected: incorrect security] from MAC address XX,\x0a'
```

Here is a not correctly processed message:

```
[2024-02-16T22:24:42.364319] Incoming log entry; input='<12>Feb 16 21:24:42 : [Access Control] Device  with MAC address XX is blocked to access the network.\x0a', msg='0x7feb13e22000', rcptid='0'
[2024-02-16T22:24:42.364319] json-parser(): no marker at the beginning of the message, skipping JSON parsing ; input='Control] Device  with MAC address XX is blocked to access the network.', marker='@cee:'
[2024-02-16T22:24:42.364319] json-parser(): no marker at the beginning of the message, skipping JSON parsing ; input='Control] Device  with MAC address XX is blocked to access the network.', marker='@cim:'
[2024-02-16T22:24:42.364503] Outgoing message; message='<12>1 2024-02-16T21:24:42+01:00 : - Access - - Control] Device  with MAC address XX is blocked to access the network.\x0a'
```

If I understood correctly the difference is that for the second message the name of the application is not given. How can I fix the problem ? Thanks